# iOS app SSL handshake failed

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I am making an app to login to an aspx website over HTTPS by passing login credentials in a post method. When checking the response using Charles Proxy I can see a SSL Handshake failed error from seal.verisign.com, I am then taken back to the login page. I am not sure what I need to do to solve this issue.

I am testing this in the iPhone simulator.

I do not have access to the server implementation.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 155):

On iOS >= 10.3, after installing the Charles Proxy certificate (as per @ashish-verma's excellent answer), you also need to enable it through *Settings* -> *General* -> *About* -> *Certificate Trust Settings*:

[image: Enable SSL root certificate on iOS 10.3 and up]

Full setup here: http://www.devsbedevin.net/debugging-ios-ssl-traffic/

Answer (score 19):

If installing the certificate still doesn't help you, then it may be due to SSL Pinning.

From charlesproxy.com:

> SSL Pinning
>   Note that some apps implement SSL certificate pinning which means they specifically validate the root certificate. Because the app is itself verifying the root certificate it will not accept Charles's certificate and will fail the connection. If you have successfully installed the Charles root SSL certificate and can browse SSL websites using SSL Proxying in Safari, but an app fails, **then SSL Pinning is probably the issue**.

Comment: is there any way to solve the SSL pinning issue with Charles Proxy ?

Comment: @tingason using Android, and patch the app to disable SSL Pinning, or patch iOS app and re sign it.

Comment: @tingason for ios: jail-breaked iphone, then use iOS SSL Kill Switch, or rooted android, use (based on Xposed) JustTrustMe or Android-SSL-TrustKiller, detailed explanation please check [my post](http://www.crifan.com/charles_cannot_crawl_parital_https_request_package_which_using_ssl_cerificate_pinning)  written in Chinese

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps testing on an actual device will give more insight?

To do that in Charles:

1. Goto Proxy: Proxy Settings...
2. Proxies tab: Enter "8888" in the HTTP Proxy port: field
3. SSL Tab: make sure the "Enable SSL Proxying" is on

On your dev machine:

1. Goto System Preferences: Network: Wifi: Advanced: TCP/IP Tab: Make note of the IPV4 Address:  (i.e. 10.0.1.101)

On your iDevice:

1. Goto http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt from your device and download Charles SSL certificate
2. Okay the certificate as trusted (be sure to disable or remove it once you're done)
3. Goto the Settings App: Wifi: Select the detailed disclosure button (round blue button with the white arrow) for your network
4. Under HTTP Proxy, select "Manual"
5. Enter in the address from step (dev machine 1.) into the Server field, and the port number from step (charles 2.)

Finally:

1. Restart Charles
2. Run Safari on your iDevice to test. This should prompt Charles to display a dialog box to allow or deny SSL proxying. Obviously allow and you should be good to go.

More Info at Charles's site: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/

Also, are you getting a response to the connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge method?

Comment: The Step 1 of "On your iDevice" was something I didn't know and must have definitely saved me a couple of hours. Thanks.

Comment: Restarting Charles worked for me as mentioned in this comment after getting new certificate (since old one was expired). You might need to reset your Charles certificate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install SSL certificate to resolve this issue.

Follow these steps

1. Open **Safari** browser on **iOS** **Simulator**
2. Type **"www.charlesproxy.com/getssl"** in address bar
3. Install the **SSL** certificate
4. Restart **Charles Proxy**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the server doesn't have a valid certificate for the url you are using.
Did you check that?

If you try the url using a browser, does it give you a warning?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SSL certificate on mobile device.

Search online for how to install SSL certificate for Charles Proxy.

Comment: Please note that [overt self-promotion is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). I suggest you edit the links to your blog out of your answers. They are only allowed in your profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all old user credentials, then Re-Install new ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If running on the simulator, just restart both Charles Proxy and the simulator, making sure Charles Proxy starts first